# BinarySearch Built-in and BinarySearch1 Self defined help

Tags: discrete

I am trying to create my own binary search to compare with the built-in function. I have referenced the docs, but the output is not correct and implies an issue. Please help with my function syntax and why the built-in is producing an error output. [Doc Reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/BinarySearch.html)
My code is **The photo below better reflects the spaces and tabs

```
binarySearch1[x_Integer, A : {__Interger}] := 
    Module[{n, i, j, m, location},
    n = Length[A];
    i = 1;
    j = n;
    While[i < j,
        m = Floor[(i + j)/2];
        If[x > A[[m]],
            i = m + 1,
            j = m
          ]
      ];
     If[x == A[[i]],
        location = i,
        location = 0
        ];
        location
     ]
```

[image: My function and output and the built-in]

Comment: First step would be to change `Interger` to `Integer`... After that, it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Moreover, the blue code in the screen shot tells me that you forgot to run ``Needs["Combinatorica`"]`` in order to load the Combinatorica packages. (The message issued by `Needs` is only a warning and can be ignored.)

Comment: Obviously, I missed that typo, but thanks for the quick eyes to see that! Everything works smoothly now!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: There should be automated tools in the Wolfram Language, so as to properly translate "Interger" for those of us from NJ.